# java: output file

Tags: java

How do you print out multiple strings per file

Comment: I run it with my source file that I have downloaded, it is a file that has employee names, departments, positions and salary

Comment: A guess is that when you do your `PrintWriter`, you're REPLACING the file, and not appending to it. Try `PrintWriter deptoutput = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(deptFile, true));`

Answer (score 0):

If the file already exists, you're replacing it with a new File with the last employee for each department. One thing you could do is not replace the file, but append to it using the following:

`PrintWriter deptoutput = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(deptFile, true));`

The above will cause issues if you choose to run the application multiple times as you'll get duplicate information. I would recommend restructuring your application, collecting all information within the application, then only make one output call per department.